# onTapDown in Flutter doesn't register quick taps

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code to detect a tapdown:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTapDown: (details) {
    // do action
  },
```

It works fine, *except* for really short taps.

From the documentation:

> **This is called after a short timeout**, even if the winning gesture has not yet been selected. If the tap gesture wins, [onTapUp] will be called, otherwise [onTapCancel] will be called.

Why the timeout? Can I get rid of the timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onPanDown` is instantly triggered. Using:

```
GestureDetector(
  onPanDown: (details) {
    // do action
  },
```

Solved my issue.